# ASP.NET SetFocus works on Localhost but not working on Server

Tags: c#, setfocus

I have a website that is working well, except for one problem. I have a text field which takes in ID value of the member and populates the details of the member.

When I try to fetch details of a user, the Cursor should automatically show up in the textbox, whether the results were found or not. This works perfectly on the localhost project but doesnt work on the Production.

Using ASP.NET and C# for this.

```
Control textControl = FindControl("txtIDValue");
            if (textControl != null)
            {

                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).SetFocus(textControl);
            }
```

The above is the code I use. Can someone please help me? I have been struggling with this past 2 days!

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an exception with this `alert(txtIDValue);`?

Comment: I have commented that part already... So no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
TextBox textControl = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtIDValue");
if (textControl != null)
{
    textControl.Focus();
}
```

This way you don't use the `ScriptManager` and cast the control to a `TextBox`.

Comment: Check the console, make sure you do not have any exceptions there. If there is any exception, let me know what it is.

Comment: I find this error: Error 215 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Does the page run at all? Or do you just get that error in the Asp.net error page ? (the yellow page), or do you get that error in the browser's console?

Comment: I get the error on the console for my Localhost, but it runs fine on the production. Page works

Comment: So the page works and you still get that error. That is very strange. Try re-setting your Virtual  Directory for this project. There is no reason for this error.